# Using Cookies to save slideToggle current state

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, refresh, slidetoggle

I need a little assistance getting started on how to use the cookie [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

I have a basic nav, ul inside of a ul, and using slideToggle to show/hide the sections. I would like it to keep its current state after the page is refreshed. I have seen examples oh how people have done this with single divs, but the cookie code is a bit confusing to me. If anyone can point me in the right direction, or get me started in my specific example, I would be very much appreciative.

Here is my current script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navHeader').children(".subNav").hide();

    $('.navHeader').on('click', function(){
        $(this).children('.subNav').slideToggle(100);
        $(this).siblings().children('.subNav').slideUp(100);
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id='navMenu'>
    <ul class='mainNav'>
        <li class='navHeader'>Section 1
            <ul class='subNav'>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='navHeader'>Section 2
            <ul class='subNav'>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='navHeader'>Section 3
            <ul class='subNav'>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='navHeader'>Section 4
            <ul class='subNav'>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about cookies here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

It also contains functions you can readily use in your code.

**Edit:** Start reading about cookies there, then try by yourself to implement what you need. If you need further assistance please let us know. It is always best to try and get it done because it will earn you some valuable experience. You don't really need a jQuery plugin for this task, but that is just my opinion.